# Backbone - avoid re-rendering on each delete

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I would like to avoid re-rendering on each 'add remove reset' event on Backbone.Collection.

So in a Backbone.View I might have:

```
this.listenTo(this.collection,'remove',this.render);
```

if I delete/remove a bunch of models, it's going to render for as many models as I delete.

What is the best way to avoid this?

Comment: one way to avoid it is to fire a custom event when all the models have been removed, and to listen to that custom event, instead of listen to vanilla 'remove'.

Comment: So how would you delete several models?  Is there a collection somewhere that you're clearing out?

Comment: You've already answered yourself from what we see here.  If you want more you'll need to be specific.

Comment: http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-reset ?

Comment: so you're saying the comment I made was a good idea, that's something that I had just made up while writing the question. I am looking for an example, best practices, something more. Someone who has tried it before.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have re-render the whole view just because something needs to go away.

You could have a method to remove just one model's hunk of the view:

```
model_removed: function(m) {
    // find m's chunk of the view inside this.$el
    // and remove it.
    this.$('whatever-selector-you-need').remove();
}
```

and then bind that to the `'remove'` event:

```
this.listenTo(this.collection, 'remove', this.model_removed);
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/fL0zr67s/

Alternatively, you could nest your views so that you have one sub-view for each model and an overall view for the collection. The collection view would create and render the model views as needed and then simply call [`remove`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-remove) on the sub-view in response to a `'remove'` event from the collection.